# Blender: bmesh uv-coordinates bug?

Tags: python, blender

i wrote a function in blender-python that should search two loops from a bmesh uv layer that should have neither identical u nor v coordinates. They should also be from the same face. However it's not working correctly and the code produces weird output in between as can be seen through the output of the print command further down.
The `print(loop1[uv_layer].uv)` command outputs correctly but if i print out the individual values with `print(loop1[uv_layer].uv[1])` the output is wrong.

Thanks for your help!

```
def get_different_uv_loops(bm):

loop1 = None
loop2 = None

for f in bm.faces:
    if loop2 is None:
        # set start loop
        for start_loop in f.loops:
            if loop2 is None:
                loop1 = start_loop

                # compare start loop uvs against other loop uvs from face
                for l in f.loops:
                    if loop2 is None:
                        # is u and v of compared loop different from start loop u and v?
                        if loop1[uv_layer].uv[0] != l[uv_layer].uv[0] and \
                            loop1[uv_layer].uv[1] != l[uv_layer].uv[1]:

                            print(loop1[uv_layer].uv[0])
                            print(loop1[uv_layer].uv[1])
                            print(l[uv_layer].uv[0])
                            print(l[uv_layer].uv[1])

                            loop2 = l
                            face = f 

                            print(loop1[uv_layer].uv)
                            print(loop2[uv_layer].uv)
                    else:
                        break
            else:
                break
    else:
        break

return (loop1, loop2, face)
```

output:

```
0.5
1.490115550950577e-07
1.0
0.5 
<Vector (0.5000, 0.000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 0.000)>
```

Comment: The first variation is related to [storing binary floating point](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78459/935), not sure why the second vector varies by 0.5. You probably want to use [`isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) to compare locations. Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49346/935) help?

Comment: Ok it seems to be a rounding problem. When i apply round() to the values they are fine.